# Issue with ROW_NUMBER and DISTINCT

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I have following query

```
SELECT Dept
      ,ID      
  FROM (SELECT TOP (@RowTo) ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Dept) AS ROWID,      
               Dept    
              ,ID
          FROM Department 
         WHERE Dept LIKE @Team + '%') as Calls        
 WHERE RowID >= @RowFrom AND RowID <= @RowTo
```

I need to get a `DISTINCT` list of the Departments, but need the paging that this query returns.  I have tried to rewrite this many a times, but I'm failing miserably.  Anyone got any pointers?

Table data

```
ID    Department  Location
1     HR          London
2     HR          Berlin
9     HR          Paris
11    HR          Amsterdam
12    IT          Berlin
13    IT          London
15    HR          New York
18    IT          Paris
19    IT          Barcelona
20    HR          Barcelona
21    Finance     Paris
22    Finance     London
23    Finance     New York
```

Using the following SQL:

```
SELECT Dept
      ,ID      
  FROM (SELECT TOP (@RowTo) ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Dept) AS ROWID,      
               Dept    
              ,ID
          FROM Department 
         WHERE Dept LIKE @Team + '%'
         ORDER
            BY Dept) as Calls        
 WHERE RowID >= @RowFrom AND RowID <= @RowTo
```

Returns:

```
Dept    ID
HR      1
HR      2
HR      9
HR      11
IT      12
IT      13
HR      15
IT      18
IT      19
HR      20
```

Now, I know that I need to drop out the `ID` column in order to get a `DISTINCT` list of values for the `Department` column.  By doing so, I only get:

```
Dept
HR
IT
```

None of the `Finance` Departments are dropping into the result set because the sub query is returning the `TOP` 10 records which it's not part of.  This is where I'm no getting stuck.

Comment: Which ID should go with each distinct Dept? And *do* you need the IDs to begin with?

Comment: Your query is missing an `ORDER BY` clause that should match its TOP clause: `...(SELECT TOP (@RowTo) ... ORDER BY <whatever order you need>)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`DISTINCT` is evaluated last or almost last of all the clauses. Therefore, it can't be used on the same level as `ROW_NUMBER` to get the results you want. Either use a derived table with `DISTINCT`:

```
SELECT
  Dept
FROM (
  SELECT
    Dept,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Dept) AS RowID
  FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT
      Dept
    FROM Department
    WHERE Dept ... 
  ) AS d
) AS Calls
WHERE RowID ...
;
```

or replace `DISTINCT` with `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT
  Dept
FROM (
  SELECT
    Dept,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Dept) AS RowID
  FROM Department
  WHERE Dept ...
  GROUP BY Dept
) AS Calls
WHERE RowID ...
;
```

Answer (score 3):

#### Use `DENSE_RANK()` instead

`DENSE_RANK()` associates the *same* rank value with peer rows that aren't strictly ordered given the window function's `ORDER BY` clause. Unlike `RANK()`, however, `DENSE_RANK()` produces no gaps, which is useful for `DISTINCT` semantics.

```
SELECT Dept
      ,ID      
  FROM (SELECT TOP (@RowTo) DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY Dept) AS ROWID,      
               Dept    
              ,ID
          FROM Department 
         WHERE Dept LIKE @Team + '%'
         ORDER
            BY Dept) as Calls        
 WHERE RowID >= @RowFrom AND RowID <= @RowTo
```

#### How does it work?

This is best explained by example:

```sql
SELECT
  v, 
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY v),
  RANK()       OVER(ORDER BY v),
  DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY v)
FROM (
  VALUES('a'),('a'),('a'),('b'),
        ('c'),('c'),('d'),('e')
) t(v);
```

The above yields:

```
| V | ROW_NUMBER | RANK | DENSE_RANK |
|---|------------|------|------------|
| a |          1 |    1 |          1 |
| a |          2 |    1 |          1 |
| a |          3 |    1 |          1 |
| b |          4 |    4 |          2 |
| c |          5 |    5 |          3 |
| c |          6 |    5 |          3 |
| d |          7 |    7 |          4 |
| e |          8 |    8 |          5 |
```

I've recently written a [blog post that explains this more thoroughly](http://blog.jooq.org/2013/10/09/sql-trick-row_number-is-to-select-what-dense_rank-is-to-select-distinct/)